# Spark: multiplication of two numbers results in NULL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, precision

I am having an issue where I am multiplying values from two columns: `(DecimalType(38,10)` and `DecimalType(38,16))`. The resulting column is of `DecimalType(38,22)`. I have disallowed the precision loss. As per the below documentation, I would expect that the result would be `NULL` only in case of very huge numbers, which overflow available space. However, even though I am getting some nulls, it is all cases like the following:
[image]

Such operation I would expect to work, given we basically multiply 30858938444.540 by 1.

Both decreasing the scale, and turning the precision loss configuration true solves the issue.

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me this behavior.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to do the multiplication, we can't help much without it

Comment: i'm not able to replicate your issue with a simple `c1 * c2`.

Comment: @samkart you'd have to set `spark.sql.decimalOperations.allowPrecisionLoss=false` I bet